# Shutdown command vs cron jobs

Tags: cron, shutdown

I have a number of computers and each computer is starting cron jobs left and right.

Those are both server computers and desktop computers.

On desktop computers it would be inconvenient if a user would shutdown the computer while a cron job is running.

I am thinking of mv-ing the shutdown command, and have users shutdown via a dedicated function, which would in turn, run the shutdown command, but only once all cron jobs have stopped running.

Am i mis thinking this somehow?

Or does the shutdown command already take cron jobs into consideration?

Comment: Maybe stop a minute to consider whether all of these cron jobs could be *better-administered* as `systemd` units.  I'm personally not a huge fan of `systemd`, but it's the only game in town now, and I have no doubts that under some scenarios it does a better job than `cron`...  actually `cron` itself is run as a `systemd` job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shutdown command doesn't know anything about cron jobs, but if you're on a modern system then shutdown is actually handled by systemd, and systemd knows about [inhibitors](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/), which allow you to prevent certain activities -- like system shutdown, suspend, etc -- while a command is running.

You can use the [`systemd-inhibit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-inhibit.html) command to run a command with an inhibitor lock. So if you have a cron job that does something that shouldn't be interrupted -- like making a system backup, or installing package upgrades -- you can replace something like...

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/backup-script.sh
```

With:

```
0 0 * * * systemd-inhibit --what=shutdown /path/to/backup-script.sh
```

Comment: So i was misthinking it somewhat. If i don't say a what it inhibits all possible system hiccups so that is preferred. And i put a why=cron for that gives the reason if somebody tries to shutdown.

Comment: I'm running this cron as a limited user, but systemd-inhibit requires sudo privileges. What is the best way to  tackle that, is that to just run it with sudo?

Comment: Im a bit worried about that for i need to be doing cron things where its safer to do them as an unprivileged user. Maybe it would be better to make a group, make that systemd-inhibits programs group. Assign the cron user to that group as well. And then the cron user can maybe achieve inhibit functionality without getting root privileges. Am i thinking this correctly?

Comment: You could also run your cron jobs as `root` and do something like `systemd-inhibit sudo -u anotheruser /path/to/script.sh`; done this way, you don't need to assign sudo privileges to anybody.

Comment: Are there any security dangers associated with that method?

Comment: None that spring immediately to mind.